# jsp page is not loaded from html page

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

jsp page is not loaded instead the browser shows "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". Database is connected to MySQL query browser from Netbeans 8.1. Why the page is not loaded? What is the remedy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some of the possible Issues :-**

JDBC Driver i.e thin driver seems to be missing or not getting loaded while establishing the connection using JDBC Code in your JSP File.

Try to do the following as mentioned below:-

1.Add your mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar in the LIB folder of your Java Project .

2.Right click in you project; click on "Clean and Build";
After that go to the netbeans project folder;

3.Try executing a Your Project  and your JSP page should be able to connect to the DB using JDBC API Code.